# vscode assistance with building cpptools needed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Ubuntu 18.04 ARM64

I have download and built vscode and this appears to be working.

I can see the extension market place and install extensions.  The C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing install but gets a dependency install failure sometimes:

```
Updating C/C++ dependencies...

Downloading package 'Mono Framework Assemblies' (5368 KB)  Done!

Installing package 'Mono Framework Assemblies'
Failed at stage: installPackages
Error: end of central directory record signature not found
```

It seems to succeed on the second attempt but I'm not convinced.

So I have cloned vscode-cpptools and would like to built it myself but I'm not sure what dependencies it has or how to build it correctly.

Any tips appreciated!

So following the build and debug guide at:

```
$ git clone -b release https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools
$ cd vscode-cpptools/Extension
$ npm install ! should install all dependencies but it forgets gulp
$ npm install gulp ! Manually install. I wonder what else it forgets
$ vsce package ! Should trigger the build and make the vsix package.
```

So the package is created and when I try and install it via the vscode extensions I get

```
Unable to start the C/C++ language server. IntelliSense features will be disabled. Error: Missing binary at ~/.vscode-oss-dev/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.22.1/bin/Microsoft.VSCode.CPP.Extension.linux.
```

Me thinks there are a lot of other dependencies that are missing!!!

Looking in the Extension bin folder and two important binaries are missing:

```
Microsoft.VSCode.CPP.Extension.linux
Microsoft.VSCode.CPP.IntelliSense.Msvc.linux
```

I also tried this on Intel Ubuntu 18.04 and while the Intel build appeared to do a whole lot more it also fails to build the binaries.

Comment: There are pretty extensive docs for it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: $ git clone -b release https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools
$ cd vscode-cpptools
$ npm install ! should install all dependencies but it forgets gulp
$ npm install gulp ! I wonder what else it forgets

Comment: Can't be done because cpptools requires some runtime dependencies that are provided by MS and binaries for Linux ARM64 are not so provided.  So vscode will work but vscode-cpptools will not.

Comment: Found the answer in here : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/429 which indicates there is no support for Aaarch64 Arm64 at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in here : [github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/429](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/429) which indicates there is no support for Aaarch64 Arm64 at this point in time.